# Conditional 'field' in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is it possible to achieve conditional field in columnDefs in ag-grid? I want whenever there is 'anotherValue' in rowData to render 'anotherField' for the field value in columnDefs.

Example I have data:

```
this.gridOptions.rowData = [
  { id: 5, value: 10 },
  { id: 10, value: 15 },
  { id: 15, value: 20, anotherValue: 500 },
];
```

And column definition:

```
this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'ID',
    field: 'id',
    width: 100,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Value',
    field: 'anotherValue' ? 'anotherValue' : 'value', //this part doesn't work
    cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,
    width: 100,
  },
];
```

Please see the stackblitz example. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-hzr31v?file=app/my-grid-application/my-grid-application.component.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `valueGetter` instead of `field` for custom values. Read more about [valueGetter](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/value-getters/)

```
this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'ID',
        field: 'id',
        width: 100,
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Value',
        valueGetter: this.anotherValueGetter, // THIS PART 
        cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,
        width: 100,
      },
    ];
```

anotherValueGetter will be a method that checks the validation.

```
  anotherValueGetter(params) {
    return params.data.anotherValue? params.data.anotherValue : params.data.value;
  }
```

See the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-fom85a?file=app/my-grid-application/my-grid-application.component.ts)

Comment: This is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it supports that. You could modify your data though if that's an option:

```
this.gridOptions.rowData = [
  { id: 5, value: 10 },
  { id: 10, value: 15 },
  { id: 15, value: 20, anotherValue: 500 },
].map(entry => ({
    ...entry,
    value: entry.anotherValue ? entry.anotherValue : entry.value
}));
```

And then your grid would always just be "value":

```
this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'ID',
    field: 'id',
    width: 100,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Value',
    field: 'value',
    cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,
    width: 100,
  },
];
```

See your updated stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-w1hnfp?file=app/my-grid-application/my-grid-application.component.ts